# How to get innertext from a node without end tag?

Tags: xpath, html-parsing, html-agility-pack

I have following nodes:

```
  <option value="trz4.htm">TextIwant1
  <option value="trz5.htm">TextIwant2
  <option value="trz6.htm">TextIwant3
  <option value="trz2.htm">TextIwant4
```

HtmlAgilityPack doesn't get "TextIWant1..." as innerText. I am getting only empty strings:

```
private static List<string> GetTextIWant(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes)
    {
        return nodes.Select(node => node.InnerText)).ToList();
    }
```

How can I get "TextIwant1.."?

Comment: Are you sure the error is in the code you you included or could it already occur in the calling routine which has retrieved the `nodes` from the source document. Maybe you should provide some more context.

Comment: Ok, for next time I will. I have already solved it.

Comment: You should offer the solution as your own answer in order to close it. Otherwise your answer will always stay open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved it. I thought that "TextIwant" belongs to option node, but it is actually next node.

```
private static List<string> GetTextIWant(IEnumerable<HtmlNode> nodes)
{
    return nodes.Select(node => node.NextSibling.InnerHtml)).ToList();
}
```